# Determining segue and unwind VC identities?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm a newbie to Objective-C, although I've coded in other languages.

Can somebody please give me a SIMPLE answer on how to identify which VC I've "unwound" from in a segue? Excuse my poor use of the language!

I have one Scene that can segue into two different scenes depending on buttons pushed. When unwinding from either of these scenes, I want to perform specific actions with the data passed back. But in order not to crash the the whole thing (this keeps happening!), I need to determine which scene I'm returning from, i.e. the identity or identifier of the source(?) scene of the unwind and then use this information to determine what actions to take.

I've tried setting the segue identifiers in Storyboard and trying to get these values in both destination and source, but they always come up null when debugging.

Here is a snippet of code that's probably clearer than my bumbling explanation!

```
    - (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ToDoListViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];

    // HOW DO I DETERMINE WHICH VC I’VE JUST UNWOUND FROM?

    if (/* UNWOUND FROM FIRST SCENE */) {

        // DO SOMETHING
    }
    if (/* UNWOUND FROM SECOND SCENE */) {

        // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

I've already tried the suggestion given using segue.identifier, but it continues to return "null." Here is 1) the code in question, 2) the resulting log, and 3) confirmation of segue identifier:

```
- (IBAction)unwindToList:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    ToDoListViewController *source = [segue sourceViewController];//WAS AddToDoItemViewController but did NOT work.
    NSLog(@"segue from: %@", source);
    NSLog(@"segue identifier: %@", segue.identifier);
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addItemScene"]) {
        if (source.toDoItem.flag == 1) {
        ToDoItem *item = source.toDoItem;
        if (item != nil) {
            [self.toDoItems addObject:item];
            [self.tableView reloadData];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log result:
2014-01-27 22:01:07.163 ToDoListML[1367:70b] segue from: AddToDoItemViewController: 0x8a98a20
2014-01-27 22:01:07.165 ToDoListML[1367:70b] segue identifier: (null)

And I've double checked that the segue identifier is has been set and is correct.

Comment: i have posted the answer

Comment: Hello dear, you can create different exits calls such as (IBAction)unwindToListFromScene1:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue connect you action to this.

Answer (score 0):

Identifier can be set as - select the connection - move to Attribute inspector panel

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your first Controller"])
{
        ToDoListViewController *source = [segue destinationViewController];//this line needs to be changed, it works in prepare for segue, so it must work here as well
}
else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your second Controller"])
{

}
```

Comment: Hmm... yes, I've tried this, but couldn't make it work. Let me try to recreate this and, if still no luck, I'll post the full code. Many thanks!

Comment: I've updated my original post with code after trying again to do as you suggest above... thanks.

Comment: Any ideas about the (null) result I'm getting for segue.identifier? (See the updated original question.) Many thanks!

Comment: @user3239117 I have posted answer

Comment: Yes, thank you, but segue.identifier is returning (null) in log, both in source and destination. Why might this be?